# Inconsistent vertical spacing when using different font sizes

Tags: fontsize, vertical-spacing

I am trying to create a uniform spacing between three lines, the middle of which has a different font size. However, when I try as follows, the spacing above the middle line is different from the one below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
One

\vspace{\baselineskip}
{\Huge Two\par}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
Three
\end{document}
```

This is what the generated PDF looks like:

[image: Screenshot of the PDF generated by LaTeX]

I have tried `\parbox`es and `\minipage`s, but so far have not been able to create uniform spacing.

Can anyone explain why the vertical spacing generated by the above code is different and how uniform spacing could be achieved?

Comment: Get rid of the `\par` in `{\Huge Two\par}`.  Then, while the text will still be `\Huge`, the line spacing will not act according to `\Huge`.  It will help to see this even better if the `\Huge` line contains a descender like `g`.

Comment: This indeed leads to the desired result in the above example, but I forgot to mention that I inserted the `\par` on purpose to achieve a "normal" line height when the text is wrapped in the second paragraph (say if it consisted of 20 "Two"s or so). If I omit the `\par`, the result will be very close lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to even define “uniform spacing”, but here's a possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-4]\par
\prevdepth=\maxdimen
\medskip

{\Large \lipsum*[2][1-3]\par}
\prevdepth=\maxdimen
\medskip

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

Stating `\prevdepth=\maxdimen` will make TeX use the `\lineskip` between the two lines (default value 1pt) and we can add whatever vertical space we prefer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! With your solution, the spacing is even more, i.e. exactly "uniform" (by which I meant the vertical space between the lower and upper edges of two consecutive paragraphs' letters), compared to the solution mentioned by @steven using a `\parbox` (using a `\parbox`, there was still a very small difference in the vertical spacing, which was especially apparent when using the `setspace` package's `onehalfspacing` option and `\Large` instead of `\Huge`).

Answer (score 3):

While I suggested that the `\par` in `{\Huge Two\par}` made the lines between One and Two get set with `\Huge` line spacing and advocated the removal of the `\par`, the OP replied that if the "Two" content exceeded a line width, then it would not be set with appropriate spacing within the paragraph.

An alternate approach to removing the `\par`, if the "Two" content exceeds a line, is to set it separately as `\Huge` within its own `\parbox`, as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
One

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\Huge Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g)
 Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g) Two(g)}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
Three
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick responses. I must have done something wrong in my `\parbox` attempts.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the difference between `\Huge` and `\normalsize` `\baselinskip` so simplest is just to add one and remove the other.

Dots addd to show the spacing

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
One\dotfill

\vspace{2\baselineskip}
{\Huge\vspace{-\baselineskip} Two{\normalsize\dotfill}\par}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
Three\dotfill
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Perhaps I should not have chosen `\baselineskip` as the `\vspace` amount in my example, but instead a height like `1cm`. Your solution seems to provide an even spacing between the baselines when using `\baselineskip` as `\vspace` amount, if I see and understand it correctly. However, my problem was the different spacing between the bottom and top edges of the letters. It could be solved by the solution suggested by @steven using a `\parbox`.

Comment: @alex no you can use this version use `\vspace{1cm}\vspace{\baselineskip} \Huge\vspace{-\baselineskip}` (instead of the 2)  Using a parbox you will find it (very) hard to get the space right afer the paragraph   `\parbox[t]` gives you conrol over he firs lie but loses all informaion a he boom of the box

Comment: Thank your for your explanation regarding the `\parbox` as well as how to add further spacing in your solution! My formulation "uniform spacing" was probably too ambiguous. Your solution does indeed result in exact spacing between the baselines of the first and last lines of successive paragraphs. However, my goal was to produce equal spacing between the bottom and top edges of the letters of successive paragraphs.